# How to open a file as plain text in TextEdit?

Tags: file, text, textedit

I have a *.rtf file which I want to open as plain text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextEdit > Preferences > Open and Save

Check "RTF-files as RTF-code instead of formated text" and reopen the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a plain text version (without seeing all the RTF encoding) open the file, then Format > Make Plain Text (shift-command-T).  This is going to change the original in the file system, so if you do not want to lose the .rtf version, make a copy first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can leave it for others. I wanted to see all the RTF encoding.